# How do I expose imported classes outside of the class

Tags: python

I have different classes that represent records in a database

For example

```
# my_records.py:

class TableARecord:
    field1: str
    field2: str

class TableBRecord:
    field1: str
    field2: str
```

I have another class that represents the entire DB. I want to give access to the record objects as well without importing them directly, and so I have this

```
# my_db.py:

from my_records import TableARecord, TableBRecord

class DB:
    TableARecord = TableARecord
    TableBRecord = TableBRecord

    def some_functionality():
        ...

    ...
```

And so I can use this syntax:

```
a_record = DB.TableARecord()
```

And this works well.

My question is specifically about these lines:

```
TableARecord = TableARecord
TableBRecord = TableBRecord
```

Is there a better or more pythonic way to "expose" these classes to the outside?

Comment: You could just use the same import line in any other module.

Comment: Looks like a design issue to me. Why do you need this inflexible declarative construction? Why not inject the specific table records via constructor/dependency injection?

Comment: no there is no pythonic way to do this, besides the default import line in the other module

Comment: If the outer environment cannot have knowledge about these classes architecture, how is it supposed to know how to interact / use them ?

Comment: @KlausD. The Idea is that the user will only need one import to get a full db API. I'm thinking of it now and maybe the better solution is to use `import my_db` instead of `from my_db import DB` and then use `my_db.TableARecord` etc.

Comment: @SebastianWozny without more information about use cases DI seems an overdesigned approach to solving the problem.  The OPs code does what’s needed, simply.  There are plenty of cases DI is useful, but it depends on context.